# How to write down GLM formula with a 2x2 within-between experimental design

Tags: r, glm, lme4, anova

I have conducted a research in which the experimental design is 2x2.

I have a independent variable called `strum` which is a two-level factor and is within participants (so same participants in two different times). Then I have another independent variable called `cond` which is also a two-level factor and is instead treated as a between-subjects variable (so two different groups).
I would like to apply a `lmer` and a `glm` or `glmer` formula to fit the model and then apply an Anova, considering also the interaction effect. How can I write down the formula? How would be the syntax of it?

I tried with this formula:

```r
minv=lmer(pqinvolv~(strum*cond|pqinvolv)+(strum|id), data=dv_n)
```

where `pqinvolv` is the dependent variable, but it gives me an error

and also this one:

```r
minv=lmer(pqinvolv~strum*cond+(1|id), data=dv_n)
```

while this one works, but I'm not sure it consider my IV as a mixed model or just a two way repeated measure with all the variables being measured as within-subjects.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description,

```r
pqinvolv ~ strum*cond + (1 + strum|id)
```

would be an appropriate model: `strum*cond` (which expands to `1 + strum + cond + strum:cond`) specifies the main effects of `strum` and `cond` and their interaction *at the population level*, while `1 + strum|id` allows the effect of `strum` to vary among participants.  You can't include `cond` in the random effect because it's unidentifiable (i.e., since it's a between-subjects factor, you can't tell how its *effect* varies between subjects).  (I can't think of any scenario where putting the dependent variable (`pqinvolv`) anywhere on the right side of the formula makes sense.)

However, since you only have two levels of `strum`, the among-subject variation in `strum` effect is confounded with the residual variance, so you should simplify your model to

```r
pqinvolv ~ strum*cond + (1|id)
```

(This assumes you are fitting a linear mixed model, not a generalized linear mixed model with a fixed scale parameter, e.g. for Poisson or binomial responses.)

A similar situation is described in the "starling example" [here](https://bbolker.github.io/morelia_2018/notes/mixedlab.html).

Comment: I'm very thankful for your reply and you tryina helping me. I have tried with the formula you wrote down, but once I run it, ti gives me this kind of error: 

Error: number of observations (=96) <= number of random effects (=96) for term (1 + strum | id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable 

Which I think is a matter of observation since 
strum is as factor with 2 levels
cond is as factor with 2 levels
id is as factor with 48 levels. 

the total amount of obs are 96, which meant there were 48 participants